# SQL Server 2012 String splitting

Tags: sql-server, text-mining

I have this table on my database that's filled with big strings, and I'm trying to analyze the text thats in those strings.

I have something like this.

```
On August the third the pope talked on vatican square.... bla bla
```

What I want to know is something like this

```
Word   | Count 
ON     | 2
August | 1
the    | 2
third  | 1
```

and so one, I know I would have to break those string and find the blank spaces " ", ",", ". " and so on so that the function knows that is a word just before that and after is the string < length.

The results should go to a new table, as showned above.

How exactly would I achieve that with a SQL function?

Comment: First, SQL Server has its own full-text search *and* data mining services. You shouldn't try to parse text by yourself. Second, there are dozens of duplicate questions and several options to split a string [as shown here](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)

Answer (score 1):

You could split and count:

```
DECLARE @t NVARCHAR(400)='On August the third the pope talked on vatican square.'

;WITH tally AS
(
  SELECT TOP 1000  rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 1/0)
  FROM master..spt_values
), cte AS(     
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(' ' + @t + ' ', rn + 1,
CHARINDEX(' ', ',' + @t + ' ', rn + 1) - rn -1),'.', ''), ',','') AS word
FROM tally
WHERE rn <= LEN(' ' + @t + ' ') - 1
    AND SUBSTRING(' ' + @t + ' ', rn, 1) = ' '
)
SELECT word, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM cte
GROUP BY word;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/426118)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════════╦═══════╗
║  word   ║ total ║
╠═════════╬═══════╣
║ August  ║     1 ║
║ On      ║     2 ║
║ pope    ║     1 ║
║ square  ║     1 ║
║ talked  ║     1 ║
║ the     ║     2 ║
║ third   ║     1 ║
║ vatican ║     1 ║
╚═════════╩═══════╝
```

Comment: There are dozens of duplicate questions. This is simply [one of the options](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) and not the fastest. The fastest by orders of magnitude is to use a SQLCLR helper function

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @text NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'On August the third the pope talked on vatican square.... bla bla'

SELECT t.display_term, COUNT(*)
FROM sys.dm_fts_parser('"' + @text + '"', 1049, NULL, 1) t
WHERE t.special_term = 'Exact Match'
GROUP BY t.display_term
```

Output -

```
--------------- -----------
august          1
bla             2
on              2
pope            1
square          1
talked          1
the             2
third           1
vatican         1
```

Comment: +1 for a *different* technique than those posted in the myriad duplicate questions. How about performance though?

Comment: Good question ;) really i tested `dm_fts_parser` on `2Gb` table (`~1Mb` per row). Faster than `CTE` and `XML`, but slower than `CLR`. In additional, user must have `sysadmin` rights...